# www directory is not there when I open var

Tags: directory-structure

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. All the directories present in var are listed below:

```
backups  crash  local  log   metrics  run    tmp
cache    lib    lock   mail  opt      spool
```

Why is the www directory missing, and how can I make this right?

Comment: Did you install Apache? With Apache, the www folder will be installed. You don't tell us what webserver you are using. A www folder is only created during the webserver install. sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: Why would you expect the directory there?

Comment: Thanks. I remembered installing apache2 before. Seems I didn't. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6):

The [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY) defines the directories and `/var/www/` is not a default directory. From the link:

> Requirements
>
> The following directories, or symbolic links to directories, are required in /var.

```
Directory   Description
cache   Application cache data
lib     Variable state information
local   Variable data for /usr/local
lock    Lock files
log     Log files and directories
opt     Variable data for /opt
run     Data relevant to running processes
spool   Application spool data
tmp     Temporary files preserved between system reboots
```

> Several directories are `reserved' in the sense that they must not be used arbitrarily by some new application, since they would conflict with historical and/or local practice. They are:

```
    /var/backups
    /var/cron
    /var/msgs
    /var/preserve
```

---

[Apache uses](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372) `/var/www/html/` and creates it on installation, if it does not exists. Other webservers probably have other locations. Nginx since Ubuntu 15.10 uses this directory as well, but you can also configure it in any Nginx version to use a different directory with the [`root` directive in a site config file](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) (but beware the [pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block) that can happen with this).

If you expect a `/var/www/` I would assume you need to install apache (or a lamp-server package).

---

Otherwise ...

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/
sudo chmod 755 /var/www
sudo chown root:root /var/www
```

to create it as apache would create it.

Comment: As of at least Xenial (possibly Wily), `/var/www/html` is the default configuration file's docroot location for `nginx`.  It is created if it doesn't exist during the installation of `nginx-common` which all nginx flavors (extras, full, core, light) depend on.

Answer (score 1):

The `/var/www` folder does not have to be there by default, as shown by my install:

```
php :: /var » k
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root 4096 12 Jul   06:25   backups
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root 4096 22 Jun   00:01   cache
drwxr-xr-x 36 root  root 4096 29 Jun   22:56   lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 14 Mar   10:46   local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    9 12 Jun   02:32   lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 10 root  root 4096 12 Jul   06:25   log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root  mail 4096 21 Jun   23:56   mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root 4096 12 Jun   02:32   opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    4 12 Jun   02:32   run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  root 4096 12 Jun   03:06   spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root  root 4096 12 Jun   02:38   tmp
```

Simply create the folder with `sudo mkdir /var/www`.